# How to Compare Microsoft Access Password With User-Supplied Password?

Tags: security, ms-access, passwords

Curious as to how to compare a text box string to the password the user used to authenticate themselves when they started the Microsoft Access database.

Microsoft Access version is 2003. Users authenticate themselves using [Microsoft Access Jet security](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Jet_Database_Engine#Security).

**UPDATE:** Per CesarGon (thank you), this is really a question of comparing hashed values; how might I replicate the hashing Microsoft Access does and compare the hashes?

Comment: Maybe you should explain *why* you want to do this. You're asking about a predefined solution (which turns out to be impossible) instead of describing the actual problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: The point of this exercise is to have a password-change screen. We would like to compare the password entered versus the existing password. This way, the password is really changed.

Comment: In that case, I think that the answer I suggest below (trying to create a workspace with the provided password) may work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your change password form, you can execute an ado sql command:

```
ALTER USER user PASSWORD newpassword oldpassword
```

Just make sure the text entered for both passwords are not the same.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb177884.aspx

Comment: Thanks Jeff O! :) I will try this solution when I return to work on Monday.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do that. The passwords that users use for Jet security are hashed and stored in the System.mdw database; the passwords themselves are *not* stored, but only a hash computed from the password. There is no (practical) way to recover the password from that hash.

**Edit**. You may use the Jet API to have Jet perform the validation for you. This is some sample code:

```
'set security database.
DBEngine.SystemDB = "C:\Temp\System.mdw"  

'create a workspace.
Set wksp = DBEngine.CreateWorkspace("New", "John", "john's-password")
```

If the workspace is created, then the provided password was correct. If the password was incorrect, the workspace won't be created and an error will be raised.

Comment: Thanks CesarGon; how might I replicate the hashing Microsoft Access does and compare the hashes?

Comment: @schultkl: I've no idea. I don't know what hashing algorithm Jet uses. Sorry I can't be of assistance. :-(

Comment: @schultkl: But maybe you can programmatically call Jet to perform the validation for you; I am editing my answer to show this.

Comment: Thanks! :) +1 for honesty! I appreciate your help! :D